# Loop only once on post excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm displaying an excerpt that is pulled from an advanced custom field in wordpress. The problem I have is that the code generates a lot of spans if the post have different paragraph.

**How can I control to just generate one span**? Just show the first one I mean.

This is my code:

```
    <?php while(has_sub_field("add_more_content")): ?>
        <?php if(get_row_layout() == "new_text"): // layout: Content ?>
            <span class="post-excerpt"><?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?></span>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Which generates something like:

```
 <span class="post-excerpt">text 1</span>
 <span class="post-excerpt">text 2</span>
 <span class="post-excerpt">text 3</span>
```

Comment: add `break` after `<?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); break; ?>` but this will defeat the logic of your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable which you'll validate once then set to false so it will only execute on one loop:

```
<?php 
$add_span = true;
while(has_sub_field("add_more_content")): ?>
    <?php if(get_row_layout() == "new_text"): // layout: Content ?>
        <?php if($add_span) : ?>
            <span class="post-excerpt">         
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php if($add_span) : ?>
            </span>
            <?php 
            $add_span = false;
        endif; 
        ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```